# MySQL Function retornando NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Minha function não funciona por nada nesse mundo

O SQL está assim:

-- Function utilizada para retornar o espaço restante de uma pasta escolhida. --

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION tamanhoRestante (_idPasta INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN

    DECLARE lpasTamanho INT;      
    DECLARE lpasUsado INT;
    -- Aqui é verificado o tamanho TOTAL da pasta escolhida. --
    SELECT tamanho FROM pasta WHERE idPasta = _idPasta INTO lpasTamanho;
    -- E agora a verificação de todos os arquivos alocados nesta pasta. --
    IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario JOIN usuario_has_pasta WHERE idUsuario = usuario_has_pasta.Usuario_idUsuario > 0) THEN
    SELECT SUM(arquivo.tamanho) FROM arquivo JOIN Pasta_has_Arquivo JOIN Pasta WHERE idArquivo = Arquivo_idArquivo AND Pasta_idPasta = _idPasta INTO lpasUsado;
    ELSE SET lpasUsado = 0;
    END IF;
    -- Agora faz-se o retorno do tamanho total da pasta subtraindo o total utilizado --
RETURN lpasTamanho - lpasUsado;

END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Neste teste, o `lpasTotal = Tamanho` total da pasta selecionada, e `lpasUsado` é a soma do tamanho de todos os arquivos linkado a esta pasta (através de uma ternária `Pasta_has_Arquivo`).

O `lpasTamanho` no teste tem tamanho 100, e o `lpasTamanho` fiz o teste com 0 e 50, mas em ambos retorna Null :/

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso? Não consigo encontrar o erro.

Comment: Adiciona na pergunta o resultado do select das tabelas fazendo o favor

Comment: O select esta bastante confuso. Mas para alimentar a variavel a partir do select faça algo assim: ´SELECT tamanho  INTO lpasTamanho FROM pasta WHERE idPasta = _idPasta;´

Comment: acredito que esse [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075147/select-into-variable-in-mysql-declare-causes-syntax-error) resolve seu problema, veja como é feito o INTO.

Comment: o que você pode fazer também é usar o SET no logar do INTO.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas pessoal! O problema não é o select, fiz o teste dele e está ok, o problema está na segunda parte, o SUM.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu `select` tem alguns problemas:

- A instrução `INTO` deve estar logo após a declaração do campo no `select`;
- O campo `idPasta` está com `_` no join;
- Prefira usar `inner join`;

Ficaria mais ou menos assim após algumas correções:

```
-- Function utilizada para retornar o espaço restante de uma pasta escolhida. --
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION tamanhoRestante (_idPasta INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE lpasTamanho INT;
  DECLARE lpasUsado INT;

  -- Aqui é verificado o tamanho TOTAL da pasta escolhida. --
  SELECT tamanho
    INTO lpasTamanho
    FROM pasta
   WHERE idPasta = _idPasta;

  SET lpasUsado = 0;

  -- E agora a verificação de todos os arquivos alocados nesta pasta. --
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 = 1
               FROM usuario u
               INNER JOIN usuario_has_pasta uhp ON u.idUsuario = uhp.Usuario_idUsuario)) THEN
  BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(COALESCE(arquivo.tamanho, 0))
      INTO lpasUsado
      FROM arquivo a
      LEFT JOIN Pasta_has_Arquivo pha ON a.idArquivo = pha.Arquivo_idArquivo
      LEFT JOIN Pasta p ON pha.Pasta_idPasta = p.idPasta;
  END;
  END IF;

  -- Agora faz-se o retorno do tamanho total da pasta subtraindo o total utilizado --
  RETURN lpasTamanho - lpasUsado;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

A instrução `EXISTS` verifica se a referência retorna true, por isso é necessário colocar 1=1, que será executado apenas se o `where` for satisfeito.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Sorack!
Percebi alguns erros que tinha cometido com seu comentário, obrigado!

Porém ele ainda retorna NULL caso não existe nada no Pasta_has_Arquivo, caso eu adicione um arquivo lá e chame esta função, ele retorna o tamanho correto (Era para ele mostrar 100 caso não tivesse em um arquivo alocado, porém se eu alocar um arquivo com tamanho 5, ele mostra os exatos 95).

Comment: E perdão se estou sendo "folgado", mas poderia por gentileza me explicar oque seria este (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM usuario) ? Obrigado novamente amigo!

Comment: Vou alterar aqui então pra ficar mais usável e vc testa de novo por favor. Vou adicionar também a explicação do exists. Caso dê certo por favor aprove a resposta pra que alguém que tenha uma dúvida semelhante possa se beneficiar

Comment: Alterado e adicionada explicação do exists. Agora não deve retornar null mais

Comment: Obrigado novamente pelo seu tempo Sorack!
Infelizmente ele continua retornando NULL..

Se eu dou um SELECT * FROM pasta ele retorna os valores 
id - tamanho
1 - 100
2 - 500
3 - 500

Porém se eu der um select tamanhorestante(1) ele retorna NULL (assim como utilizando as ids 2 e 3), porém se eu adicionar qualquer arquivo na pasta, ele retorna o valor certo, exemplo:
addArquivo(pasta1, arquivo1) (supondo que esse arquivo tenha 20 de tamanho)
tamanhorestante(pasta1) retorna 80..

Comment: Tenta trocar o "SELECT SUM(arquivo.tamanho)" por "SELECT SUM(COALESCE(arquivo.tamanho, 0))"

Comment: Também testei esse COALESCE e retorna NULL.. Acho que por enquanto irei desistir dele assim.. Estou a 2 horas tentando arrumar isso, já fiz alteração no banco inteiro, em todas as triggers, já testei sem nada no banco apenas esta function, e sempre o mesmo resultado, se não tiver nada alocado a pasta no pasta_has_arquivo, ele retorna null, se tiver mais de um arquivo, ele soma e retorna o valor exatamente como deveria, o unico problema é ele estar retornando null quando não se tem nada no pasta_has_arquivo com o id da pasta.. :/
Muitissimo obrigado Sorack, e desculpe o incomodo..

Comment: Ah sim, já sei qual o problema Kauan,  no segundo select mude os INNER para LEFT e mantenha o COALESCE